# How to assign objects with an index that don't have a copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, stdmap

I'm using a concurrent queue from here:

https://github.com/cameron314/readerwriterqueue

Basically there's one producer and it's producing data for multiple consumers.
Each consumer should have its own queue and each consumer has a unique identifier.

Ideally I wanted to add the queue to a std::map and map the unique identifier to the queue.

Unfortunately this doesn't work as the queue implementation does not have a copy constructor and therefore refuses to be added to a map.

How can I map the unique Ids to the queue?

Comment: It's not an ideal solution, but have a map with the keys and *pointers* to the queues?

Comment: I tried using std::unique_ptr but also these didn't work. "Real" pointers are indeed not ideal, but maybe it works. But there must be a better way ;)

Comment: @keyboard `unique_ptr` should work. Perhaps you're not familiar with how they are used? A better way would be to extend the queue with a move-constructor (and/or copy-constructor).

Comment: What did you try with unique_ptr.  If you can create a normal pointer, you should be able to create a unique pointer from that.

Comment: Well, maybe. I tried using unique_ptr as I found it in tutorials and as it already worked in my existing code - but it didn't due to the same error. I don't want to extend the queue since the author explicetely disabled it, and I guess he will have reason for it.

Comment: Just tried again, unique_ptr does not work for sure - there's the error of not having a copy constructor when inserting the unique_ptr in a map

Comment: That's because you're using it wrong.  You probably need to say `std::move(ptr)` to move the unique pointer in.  `unique_ptr` doesn't have a copy constructor, but it does have a move constructor

Comment: I don't quite get what exactly you mean, please provide an answer with code, if it works I will mark it correct and use it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue is that the queue doesn't allow copying or moving The solution, in a case like this, is to use `std::unique_ptr` which can give you a very safe solution to creating these objects on the heap.  The key is that this type can only be moved, not copied.

From your description, I think you'll want to create a `std::map<unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<ReaderWriterQueue<T>>>`.

```
class SomeClass
{
   public:
   void setUpQueue(unsigned int new_id)
   {
      std::unique_ptr<ReaderWriterQueue<T>> ptr(new ReaderWriterQueue<T>(...)); 
      // Have to use move here, othrewise, it would attempt to make a copy
      queue_map.emplace(new_id, std::move(ptr));    
      // could also do
      // queue_map.insert({new_id, std::move(ptr)}; or
      // queue_map.insert(std::make_pair(new_id, std::move(ptr));
   }

   std::map<unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<ReaderWriterQueue<T>>> queue_map;
}
```

Comment: Or `queue_map[new_id] = std::make_unique<ReaderWriterQueue<T>>(...);`

Comment: Thank you, it works! I still don't fully understand it, but it helps me think and search in the right direction :)